# Load Joomla module when document is loaded

Tags: ajax, joomla, module

I wrote a module, but it slows down the page's loading time.
I searched how to load modules with ajax, but did not find any useful topics (or just didn't understand them, english is not my native language).
My question is:
If i have a module, which lists the online members on a game server(but only if they exists in the local database), what is the correct solution to load this module after the page is loaded?

Comment: may be this link helpful http://gruz.org.ua/en/about-joomla/25-faq/50-joomla-15-ta-17-25-jak-zavantazhuvaty-moduli-za-dopomogoju-ajax.html OR change the module position end of your page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

Make an ajax call to any of your custom component task.
And the code inside that task should be like

```
 $document = &JFactory::getDocument();
 $renderer = $document->loadRenderer('module');

 $Module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_fmDataGrid');

 $Params = "param1=bruno\n\rparam2=chris";
 $Module->params = $Params;
 echo $renderer->render($Module);
```

the result you can return via ajax , and use in your html.

The other Options is

the [link](http://gruz.org.ua/en/about-joomla/25-faq/50-joomla-15-ta-17-25-jak-zavantazhuvaty-moduli-za-dopomogoju-ajax.html)  Also describing a good details but its using via module override concept.
You can follow any of these method

Hope this may help you..